# Are image formed in both the situations?-lightrays from object to mirror then our eyes and when many light rays converge?

Tags: experimental-physics

We are able to see images of objects(in mirror)

because the light after starting from the object then deflecting from mirror reaches our eyes,right?(if I'm wrong please tell) and it is also said that when many light rays converge at a single point,an image is formed at that point

So my question is,is the image formed in both the situations?to be more precise,images are formed(in the mirror) when light rays deflect off an object,then again reflecting from the mirror reaches our eyes and also images are formed when many light rays converge at a single point?

Comment: The (diverging) light you see coming from objects in the mirror is the light from the real objects reflected in the mirror. Which then is converged onto your retina.

Comment: No images are formed on the mirror.  As @DescheleSchilder points out, the only real image forms on the retina.   Note that the rays coming *from* the object are also converge at a point, that is, the object.  Looking in the mirror these rays *appear* to have converged at a spot *behind* the mirror.  Of course, there are no rays behind the mirror.  This type of apparent convergence is a *virtual image*.

Comment: Oh,so no image is formed on the surface of mirror?real images are formed on retina right?the real images are formed when light rays after deflecting from an object when reach the mirror,again after reflection,the light rays intersect in front of our retina,right?(pls rectify if I'm wrong)